# Meteor.loginWithFacebook Suddenly Producing Intermittent Timeouts when authenticating

Tags: facebook, authentication, meteor, oauth, meteor-accounts

Currently running Meteor 1.5 Release using a bundle that is deployed on our linode server. All has been ok in the past, but now in production environment when attempting to authenticate using Meteor.loginWithFacebook we are getting intermittent connection timeouts when the oauth attempts to establish the connection with Facebook server. The FB App settings appear fine. As mentioned, the logins will work most of the time but its not consistent.

We are using the popup style auth login flow.

For example: You sign in/sign out with no problem. Then repeat the same process again and its fine, and then for example you try again and it can suddenly just get hung up with a popup window trying to establish the facebook authentication.

On the server console log you will get these type of messages:

```
{"line":"431","file":"oauth.js","message":"Error in OAuth Server: Failed to fetch identity from Facebook. connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.77.6:443","time":{"$date":1505065274956},"level":"warn"}
{"line":"431","file":"oauth.js","message":"Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook. connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.77.6:443","time":{"$date":1505065292025},"level":"warn"}
Exception in onLogin callback: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.77.6:443
    at Object.Future.wait (/var/bd/site/bd/09_09_2017_22_32_30/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
    at Object.call (packages/meteor.js:213:24)
    at Object.HTTP.get (packages/http/httpcall_common.js:50:20)
    at server/auth.js:48:34
    at runAndHandleExceptions (packages/callback-hook.js:152:24)
    at packages/callback-hook.js:159:12
    at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:167:5
    at [object Object]._.extend.each (packages/callback-hook.js:128:15)
    at AccountsServer.Ap._successfulLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:166:21)
    at AccountsServer.Ap._attemptLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:356:10)
    at [object Object].methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:533:21)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1737:12)
    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:40
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
    - - - - -
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1081:14)
```

Please any help would be greatly appreciated. I cannot figure out why the timeout is occurring. It happens only sometimes.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the timeout still occur ? We are having the same issue with a different facebook ip. We suspect facebook has dead servers in the cluster

Comment: Yes, this is still happening the past few weeks. It's intermittent. It only happens sometimes , but its not good .... The only workaround I can think is to write some custom code to do a re-try if the timeout occurs... If you have a solution please let me know.

Comment: FYI - We upgraded to Meteor 1.5.2 and same issue.